# pycharm- python with selenium web driver. Get error object has no attribute driver

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to run basic automation on tesco website on selenium web driver on python using PyCharm.
I am able to create 1 function and have everything within it and it works. However when I split it all into different functions I get the following error message at:

```
driver = self.driver
```

> AttributeError: 'FirstTest' object has no attribute 'driver'

**My code so far:**

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class FirstTest(unittest.TestCase):

def test_setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    self.driver.get("http://tesco.com")

    self.tearDown()

def test_websiteCheck(self):
    driver = self.driver
    assert "Tesco - Supermarkets | Online Groceries, Clubcard & Recipes" in driver.title

    self.tearDown()

def test_loginPage(self):
    driver = self.driver
    signIn = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sign in")
    signIn.click()
    username = self.driver.find_element_by_name("username")
    username.send_keys("test1234@hotmail.com")
    password = self.driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    password.send_keys("test")
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/button").click()

def test_pickingGroceries(self):
    self.driver = self.driver
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/nav/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/a").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/nav/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a/h3/span").click()
```

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not calling test_SetUp function anywhere and not returning anything from test_SetUp function.My suggestion would be use **init** function instead of test_SetUp.Then in other functions you are creating driver=self.driver, so use driver.functions instead of self.driver again.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest

class FirstTest(unittest.TestCase):

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    self.driver.get("http://tesco.com")

    self.tearDown()

def test_websiteCheck(self):
    driver = self.driver
    assert "Tesco - Supermarkets | Online Groceries, Clubcard & Recipes" in 
    driver.title

    self.tearDown()

def test_loginPage(self):
    driver = self.driver
    signIn = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sign in")
    signIn.click()
    username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
    username.send_keys("test1234@hotmail.com")
    password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    password.send_keys("test")

def test_pickingGroceries(self):
    driver = self.driver
```

Comment: thank you. i understand the silly mistake of using self.driver. it makes a lot of sense. however  when i change the setup  to __init_i get the error of TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: create an instance of the class, like

    test = FirstTest()

Then call methods on that instance.like

test.test_loginpage()

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `test_SetUp(self)` first?
You should create a `def __init__(self):` function instead that will get run upon creating an object instance of the class